# Importing implicit methods in scalatest

Tags: scala, implicit, scalatest

I'm struggling to understand why implicit imports do not work as I expect them in scalatest. The simplified failing example (using spark, but I can make it fail with my custom class also) is as follows:

```
class FailingSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MySparkContext {

    val testSqlctx = sqlctx
    import sqlctx.implicits._

    "sql context implicts" should "work" in {
        val failingDf = Seq(ID(1)).toDS.toDF
    }
}
```

The MySparkContext trait creates and destroys spark context in `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, and makes `sqlctx` available (already having to reassign it to a local variable in order to import implicits is a puzzle, but maybe for a different time). The `.toDS` and `.toDF` are then implicit methods imported from `sqlctx.implicits`. Running the test results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

If I move import into test block things work:

```
class WorkingSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MySparkContext {

    "sql context implicts" should "work" in {      
        val testSqlctx = sqlctx
        import sqlctx.implicits._

        val workingDf = Seq(ID(1)).toDS.toDF
    }
}
```

Any ideas why can't I import implicits at the top level of the test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beforeAll` runs before any of the tests, but does not run before the constructor for the class. The order of operations in the first snippet is:

1. Constructor invoked, executing `val testSqlctx = sqlctx` and `import sqlctx.implicits._`
2. `beforeAll` invoked
3. Tests run

And the order of operations for the second snippet:

1. `beforeAll` invoked
2. Tests run, executing `val testSqlctx = sqlctx` and `import sqlctx.implicits._`

Assuming you give your `SparkContext` a default (`null`) value and initialize it in `beforeAll`, the first order of operations would try to use `sqlctx` when it is still `null`, thus causing the null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks, so obvious in hindsight! So I guess I should initialize things properly in the constructor of the trait, rather than in  the `beforeAll` method.